# Change X-axis for timeseries plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

So I have a dataframe like this:

| YM | YQMD | YQM | Year | Quarter | Month | Day | srch_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-11 | 2012-4-11-01 | 2012-4-11 | 2012 | 4 | 11 | 01 | 3033780585 |
| 2012-11 | 2012-4-11-02 | 2012-4-11 | 2012 | 4 | 11 | 02 | 2812558229 |
| .. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2013-06 | 2013-2-06-26 | 2013-2-06 | 2013 | 2 | 06 | 26 | 5000321400 |
| 2013-06 | 2013-2-06-27 | 2013-2-06 | 2013 | 2 | 06 | 27 | 3953504722 |

Now I want to plot a lineplot. I did it with this code:

```
#plot lineplot
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(14,8)})

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_monthly, x ='YQMD', y = 'click_bool')
plt.ylabel('Number of Search Queries')
plt.xlabel('Year-Month')
plt.show()
```

This is the plot that I got and as you can see, the x-axis you cannot see the dates etc, because they are too much.
[image]

The pattern of the plot is the right way that I want it, but is it possible to get the x-axis like this below?:

[image]